# Delete nodes from binary search tree, without having parent stored inside the structure

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

as a n exercise i am working on a binary search tree. I have managed to search through the binary tree, and add nodes, but now that i try to find a way to delete, i seem to be stuck at **how to determine who is the parent of a node** that is to be deleted.

So to start with i have this structure

```
struct BST_node {
    struct double_linked_list *data;
    struct BST_node *left;
    struct BST_node *right;
};
```

and i have also a pointer for this structure that points to root..

```
struct BST_node *BST_email_root = 0;
```

I have this function to search for a Node

```
struct BST_node *BST_find_customer(struct BST_node *root, char *email) {
if (root==NULL)
    return NULL;
if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)==0)
    return root;
else
    {
    if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)==-1)
    return BST_find_customer(root->left,email);
    else
        return BST_find_customer(root->right,email);
    }
```

that i call inside other functions, by using

```
b = BST_find_customer(BST_email_root, email);
```

and i am trying to create the function to delete nodes..What i have to is this:

```
struct BST_node *BST_delete(struct BST_node *root, char *email)
    {
    struct BST_node *temp;
    if (root==NULL)
        return root;
    else if(strcmp(root->data->data->email,email)>0)
        root->left = BST_delete(root->left, email);
    else if(strcmp(root->data->data->email,email)<0)
        root->right = BST_delete(root->right, email);
    else
        {
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
            {
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
            }
        else if(root->right == NULL)
            {
            temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            free(temp);
            }
        else if(root->left == NULL)
            {
            temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            free(temp);
            }
        else
            {
            struct BST_node *maxNode = findMaxNode(root->left);//finding the maximum in LEFT sub-tree
            root->data = maxNode->data; //Overwriting the root node with MAX-LEFT
            root->left = BST_delete(root->left, maxNode->data);//deleted the MAX-LEFT node
            }

        return root;
        }

    }
```

by using this function also

```
struct BST_node *findMaxNode(struct BST_node *root)
            {
                if(root->right == NULL) return root;
                findMaxNode(root->right);
            }
```

However this doesnt work also and i get errors

Comment: Try keeping a pointer to the previous node you have traversed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, although it's not recursive .....

To delete a node N from a BST, you need to consider the 3 cases :

1. If N is a leaf, then no problem, just delete it
2. If N has only one son, just replace N by its son ; you'll need the pointer towards the father of N to do that
3. If N has two sons, then you can replace N by the leftest son of its right son, or by the rightest son of its left son to keep the order properties.

   ```
   void *BST_delete(struct BST_node *root, char *email){

   if (root==NULL)
       return;

   struct BST_node * father = NULL;
   char which_son; //will help us in remembering if root is the right or left son of his father

   while (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email)!=0){ //first, finding root and remembering who's root father
       if(root==NULL) {
            return ;
       } else if (strcmp(email,root->data->data->email) < 0){
            father = root;
            root = root->left;
            which_son = 'l';
       } else {
            father = root;
            root = root->right;
            which_son = 'r';
       }
   }
       // now you have both the root node, and its father
   if ( (root->right == NULL) && (root->left == NULL) ){ //case 1, if it's a leaf
        free(root);
        return;
   } else if (root->left == NULL) { //case 2 
        if (which_son == 'l') {
            father->left = root->right;
        } else {
            father->right = root->right;
        }

   } else { //case 3 : here i get the "rightest" son of root's left son
       struct BSD_node * replacing_node = root->left;

       while (replacing_node->right != NULL) {
           replacing_node = replacing_node->right;
       } //now replacing_node is a leaf, and can replace root
       if (which_son == 'l') {
           father->left = replacing_node;
           replacing_node->left = root->left;
           replacing_node->right = root->right;
       } else {
           father->right = replacing_node;
           replacing_node->left = root->left;
           replacing_node->right = root->right;
       }
   }
   free (root);
   }
   ```

I changed the return value of your function to `void` , since it might not need any return value.

It can be implemented in an easier way by simply replacing the 'data' field of one node by another, but i purposely implemented it in that fashion to emphasizes the fact that the node to delete is replaced by one of his descendants.

If it doesn't seem obvious to you that the node to suppress should be replaced by the rightiest (leftiest) son of its left (right) son, then check that these are the only 2 nodes which do not present the risk of breaking the order of your BSD.

Also, this function suffers a lot from being monolithic, it would enjoy being refactorised.

Comment: Thanks for the answer very much.. I want to return only the BST_EMAIL_root which is just a pointer to the newest node of the binary tree.. I have inserted your code to my full program, however it doesnt seem to work so good... Trying to debug it further now!

Comment: i just corrected the last lines, replacing replacing_node with root in the very last `else` statement, and added a return which was missing and would provoque a seg_fault ; and yes, i wrote it on the spot, and i'm no expert (yet), so i wouldn't be surprised if a mistake or two remain hidden within, but the spirit of supppressing a node in a binary tree is here. Good luck !

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I am trying now to check my whole code, but though it seems to work..it doesnt really work.. This is driving me nuts :)